# Not able to run this commands in shell command of mysql

Tags: mysql, shell, command

the error is

```
C:\Users\admin>cd ..
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

it is showing error like this how to solve it please suggest.
thanks for suggestions in advance.

Comment: I suggest you add the code

Comment: Maybe that *is* the code? `echo 'C:\Users\admin>cd ..' | node` results in `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.